# Sinon stub only records react calls if it has been run before

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, sinon, sinon-chai

Here is my code I'm testing:

```
const CardWarsComponent = props => {
    const onSubmitCardMove = () => {
        props.floopThePig()
    }
    return <Button id="FloopButtonId" onClick={onSubmitCardMove}>FLOOP IT</Button>
};
```

When I test I do this:

```
const floopStub = sinon.stub();
const wrapper = shallow(<CardWarsComponent floopThePig={floopStub}></CardWarsComponent>)
const button = wrapper.find('#FloopButtonId').dive();
const onClick = button.prop('onClick');
onClick();
wrapper.update();
expect(floopStub).to.have.been.calledOnce();
```

I find that I get this response:

```
TypeError: (0, _chai.expect)(...).to.have.been.calledOnce is not a function
```

BUT, if I call it once already:

```
const floopStub = sinon.stub();
floopStub()
const wrapper = shallow(<CardWarsComponent floopThePig={floopMock}></CardWarsComponent>)
```

Then I get:

```
 expected floopThePig to have been called exactly once, but was called twice
floopThePig at Context.floopThePig
floopThePig at floopThePig
```

So why can I not get it called once, but after calling it once...I get the second (actual test) call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial error message you got is exactly correct - looking at [the Sinon docs](https://github.com/domenic/sinon-chai), `.calledOnce` is a not a function, it's a javascript `get` that runs code. In general, Chai expectations only seem to be functions if they need parameters.

I find this a bit annoying because `get` overloading isn't very nice and breaks our ability to reason about the code, and it sets off a bunch of lint errors, but hey ho.

Changing your expect to

```
expect(floopStub).to.have.been.calledOnce;
```

fixes the test (at least on my machine!)

The reason the code seems to "work" in your second example is because the test resolves the `calledOnce` get operation, which checks the condition and throws a test failure assertion, so there's never a chance to throw the original error by trying to call the `get` result as if it were a function.

Incidentally, it's easier to trigger the click event with enzyme's built-in `.simulate()` call. This code works fine:

```
const floopStub = sinon.stub();
const wrapper = shallow(<CardWarsComponent floopThePig={floopMock}></CardWarsComponent>);
wrapper.find('#FloopButtonId').dive().simulate('click');
expect(floopStub).to.have.been.calledOnce;
```

More info on testing React events with sinon/enzyme can be found here: https://www.leighhalliday.com/testing-react-jest-enzyme-sinon